# Wanna know tense of main clause in 2nd conditional

Tags: clauses

Actually I thought in 2nd conditionals, the if clause is in past tense and main clause in would form (don't know its tense, probably present).
But here today I was reading something and found this, here
Person A is asking person B how would your father react if you told him about your dreams.
then person B says,

> He'd tell me to go with my gut and that he'd be proud of me no matter what I did.

Every thing is fine but why did the writer use past tense (did) in it, not just do, like *He'd be proud of me no matter what I do*?

Comment: The tense of "what I do/did" is irrelevant to the conditional. **"no matter what I do"** is an adverbial phrase modifying **proud.**

Comment: So sir here the person B is talking about the things he did right? No the things he doing ?

Comment: The tense of "what I did" is vague. It relates to actions that the person might have done under those conditions.

Comment: This displays "backshifting" of tenses. Compare *He will be proud no matter what I do* and *He would be proud no matter what I did*. We match *do* to *will* and *did* to *would*. https://www.thoughtco.com/backshift-sequence-of-tense-rule-in-grammar-1689017

Comment: Writing *wanna* will make people think less of you. And we don't believe in numbered conditionals here. They're just a facile fib told to EFL students, one that's overtly harmful.

Comment: The only verb there related to the second conditional is, "**He'd tell**". All the other verbs are part of the object of "tell", not an answer to the second conditional question. It could just as easily read, "He'd tell me to go with my gut and that **he's** proud of me no matter what I **do**.